# Fixing the order of a Sankey flow graph in R / networkD3 package

Tags: r, data-visualization, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I would like to visualize a rank change (i.e. change of the relative order) of US states using a Sankey flow graph. I'm using the [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) package and came up with the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(networkD3)

df <- data_frame(origins=state.name[1:10], destinations=state.name[1:10])
lab <- c(df$origins, df$destinations)
nodes <- data.frame(node=c(0:9), name=lab)
links <- data.frame(source=c(0:9), target=c(10:19), value=rep(1,10))
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = 'source', 
              Target = 'target', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name')
```

This snippet produces the following graph:
Sankey flow graph of US states
[image]

I can change the relative order by hand now. However, I wonder whether it is possible to fix the order on the right-hand side and put e.g. Alabama on rank 3, California on rank 1, etc ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you set `iterations = 0` in `sankeyNetwork()`, you will effectively disable the algorithm which automatically determines the node placement (which is the primary purpose of the `sankeyNetwork()` function), and the nodes will be placed in the order that they appear in the `Nodes` dataframe.

```
library(networkD3)

states <- state.name[1:10]
ranks <- sample.int(10)

nodes <- data.frame(name = c(states, states[ranks]))
links <- data.frame(source = 1:10 - 1, target = order(ranks) + 10 - 1, value = 1)

sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = 'source', 
              Target = 'target', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
              iterations = 0)
```

[image]