# R Sankey Network how to Disable Descending Sort (Overlapping)

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

[image]

See how the outputs above from `Confirmed` and `Unconfirmed` overlap? I don't want that. It appears the final values `Vendor`, `TBD`, `Internal`, `No Problem Found` are sorted in descending order, causing this issue.

Ideally the flow of `Unconfirmed -> TBD` should be a straight line at the bottom of the image. Oddly enough, the first few times I ran my scripts this is how it appeared! But it doesn't appear this way anymore??

Is there any way to do what I want? Here's my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(networkD3)

# Generate Sankey Data ---------------------------------------------------------
source <- c("Barcode Scanner", "Cell Enrichment", "Consumables", "Contamination", "Cosmetic", "Dimensional", "Display", "Heaters", "Labels", "Missing Component", "Pumps", "Vials", "Barcode Scanner", "Cell Enrichment", "Consumables", "Contamination", "Cosmetic", "Dimensional", "Display", "Heaters", "Labels", "Missing Component", "Pumps", "Vials", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Unconfirmed")
target <- c("Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Vendor", "Internal", "No Problem Found", "TBD")
values <- c("18", "8", "20", "15", "7", "17", "20", "14", "9", "16", "11", "20", "8", "7", "8", "8", "8", "6", "2", "5", "4", "8", "6", "6", "98", "53", "24", "76")

# Setup Sankey Network ----------------------------------------------------------
nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(source, target)))
links <- data.frame(source = match(source, nodes$name) - 1,
                    target = match(target, nodes$name) - 1,
                    value = values)
sn <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source", 
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name", 
              units = "Complaints", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 20)

# Fix issues with Firefox rendering --------------------------------------------
htmlwidgets::onRender(sn, 'document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].setAttribute("viewBox", "")')
```

Comment: Set `iterations = 0` inside `sankeyNetwork`

Answer (score 1):

[As explained in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229334/fixing-the-order-of-a-sankey-flow-graph-in-r-networkd3-package) this provides the solution: `iterations = 0`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(networkD3)

# Generate Sankey Data ---------------------------------------------------------
source <- c("Barcode Scanner", "Cell Enrichment", "Consumables", "Contamination", "Cosmetic", "Dimensional", "Display", "Heaters", "Labels", "Missing Component", "Pumps", "Vials", "Barcode Scanner", "Cell Enrichment", "Consumables", "Contamination", "Cosmetic", "Dimensional", "Display", "Heaters", "Labels", "Missing Component", "Pumps", "Vials", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Unconfirmed")
target <- c("Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Confirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Unconfirmed", "Vendor", "Internal", "No Problem Found", "TBD")
values <- c("18", "8", "20", "15", "7", "17", "20", "14", "9", "16", "11", "20", "8", "7", "8", "8", "8", "6", "2", "5", "4", "8", "6", "6", "98", "53", "24", "76")

# Setup Sankey Network ----------------------------------------------------------
nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(source, target)))
links <- data.frame(source = match(source, nodes$name) - 1,
                    target = match(target, nodes$name) - 1,
                    value = values)
sn <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source", 
                    Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name", 
                    units = "Complaints", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 20,
                    iterations = 0)

# Fix issues with Firefox rendering --------------------------------------------
htmlwidgets::onRender(sn, 'document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].setAttribute("viewBox", "")')
```